# I can only select a region but no zone for Google Cloud Run (fully managed) services: which zone should I choose for my Google Cloud SQL server?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I have a fully managed Google Cloud Run service running in Frankfurt. I was not able to choose a zone but only a region, so I took "europe-west3". For my Google Cloud SQL server I can and have to choose a zone. I want to select the same data center for my SQL server and my service to keep the distance short and connections fast but I don't know which zone I should use (a, b, c). Do you know a way to determine which zone fits best to a fully managed Cloud Run Service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunetly you cannot choose a Zone to deploy your Cloud Run service, the control goes only until Region. However, this is not something that you should be worried about, as you can see in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/geography-and-regions):

> A zone is a deployment area for Google Cloud resources within a region

That means that even thought the resources might not be in the same Cluster or VM, they are still very close geographically and very likely to be in the same Data Center, and as mentioned in the same documentation:

> Locations within regions (Zones) tend to have round-trip network latencies of under <1ms on the 95th percentile.

So you are looking at a very low latency between your resources anyway, to the point that might not even noticible.